# Android cmake arguments method not found

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to add arguments to cmake in order to follow the Android NDK [instructions](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/asan) for using the address sanitiser. In the build.gradle file for the native module I therefore have the following:

```
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
            arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_MODE=arm", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
            cppFlags "-fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer"
        }
    }
```

When I try to sync my project (Android Studio v. 3.4.2, Win10) I get the error message:

> ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'arguments()'

I've searched the web but can't find any other mention of this problem with the 'arguments' method. I'm using gradle 3.4.2.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is this `externalNativeBuild` block located? There is a difference between putting it directly inside `android {}` and putting it inside `android { defaultConfig {}}` (e.g. the second has an `arguments` property, while the first one does not).

Comment: Thanks this fixed it since I was in fact supposed to add it in defaultConfig. And mine was indeed a duplicate question

Answer (score 33):

There are two different Gradle DSL objects both named `externalNativeBuild`, but with different properties. See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/ExternalNativeBuild) and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/ExternalNativeBuildOptions).

So you need to set the appropriate properties on the appropriate object:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_MODE=arm", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                cppFlags "-fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer"
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark this as answer.